# how to show buttons when the mouse passes on another button

Tags: python, pygame

I'm a first year computer science major and I have a semester project I need to make a maze game.

My code for the menu of the game shows one big button and 3 smaller ones at the same time.
I don't know how to hide the 3 smaller buttons ans show them only when I pass the mouse on the bigger button.

Here is my code:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()


background_color = (50, 70, 90)
  
# Define font
FONT = pygame.font.SysFont ("Times New Norman", 60)
smallfont = pygame.font.SysFont('Corbel',35)  


# Making buttons
text0 = FONT.render("LABYRINTHE", True, (255, 255, 255))
text1 = smallfont.render("niveau 1", True, (255, 255, 255))
text2 = smallfont.render("niveau 2", True, (255, 255, 255))
text3 = smallfont.render("niveau 3", True, (255, 255, 255))
rect0 = pygame.Rect(250,100,300,100)
rect1 = pygame.Rect(300,300,205,80)
rect2 = pygame.Rect(300,400,205,80)
rect3 = pygame.Rect(300,500,205,80)
# The buttons are text, rectangle and color


buttons = [
    [text0, rect0, (30,236,85)],
    [text1, rect1, (30,236,85)],
    [text2, rect2, (30,236,85)],
    [text3, rect3, (30,236,85)]]

def game_intro():
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return
            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
                for button in buttons:
                   
                    if button[1].collidepoint(event.pos):
                       
                        button[2] = background_color
                    
                    else:
                       
                        button[2] = (30,236,85)

        screen.fill((20, 50, 70))
          
        for text, rect, color in buttons:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, rect)
            screen.blit(text, rect)
        
        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(15)

game_intro()
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: consider accepting the answer if it solved your problem

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to add a flag to the button which tells if it is currently visible. Then you can draw only the buttons which are visible.

```py
...

buttons = [
    [text0, rect0, (30,236,85), True],  # text, rect, color, visible
    [text1, rect1, (30,236,85), False],
    [text2, rect2, (30,236,85), False],
    [text3, rect3, (30,236,85), False]
    ]

def game_intro():
    while True:
...
            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
                for button in buttons:
                   
                    if button[1].collidepoint(event.pos):
                        button[2] = fond_couleur
                        button[4] = True               # set visible
                    else:
                        button[2] = (30,236,85)
                        button[4] = False              # set invisible

...
          
        for text, rect, color, visible in buttons:
            if visible:                                # draw only visible buttons
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, rect)
                screen.blit(text, rect)
        
...
```

**Improvement:**

Do not use lists to represent buttons. Better use a class or `namedtuple`. By this you can use named attributes instead of `button[n]` which is way more readable.

```py
from collections import namedtuple

Button = namedtuple('Button', 'text rect color visible')

btn1 = Button(text=text1, rect=rect1, color=(30,236,85), visible=False)

if btn1.visible:
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, btn1.color, btn1.rect)
    screen.blit(btn1.text, btn1.rect)
```